# buttons ocupy 6 columns inside a panel body

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

i need to build a panel body in a sidebar where the buttons inside ocuppy 6 columns at the moment i have something like this:

[image]

i want to have each button ocupy 6 columns and not what is happening at the moment.

here is what i did so far:

```
  <div class="sidebar">
        <h4>Document</h4>
        <div class="panel-group">
            <div class="panel panel-danger">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <button class="btn btn-primary-outline btn-block">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-share"></span>
                            <br>Paragraph
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <button class="btn btn-primary-outline btn-small">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-share"></span>
                            <br>
                            <span class="fontSize">Image</span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <button class="btn btn-primary-outline btn-small">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-share"></span>
                            <br>
                            <span class="fontSize">Image</span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <button class="btn btn-primary-outline btn-small">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-share"></span>
                            <br>Heading
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel panel-default">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <div class="sidebar">
        <h4>Document</h4>
        <div class="panel-group">
            <div class="panel panel-danger">
                <div class="panel-body row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <button class="btn btn-primary-outline btn-block button">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-share"></span>
                            <br>Paragraph
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <button class="btn btn-primary-outline btn-block">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-share"></span>
                            <br>
                            <span class="fontSize">Image</span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <button class="btn btn-primary-outline btn-block">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-share"></span>
                            <br>
                            <span class="fontSize">Image</span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <button class="btn btn-primary-outline btn-block">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-share"></span>
                            <br>Heading
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel panel-default">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Changed all button's class to btn-block from btm-small. Hope it helps

Comment: id doesn't work with me, i have a col-md-2 above i want to wrap everything inside a col-md-2